# PHP fopen problems

Tags: php

How do I create a file in php?
I have tried using...

```
$num = file_get_contents('qnum/qnum.txt');
$newFile = 'question'.$num.'.txt';
$newNum = $num++;
$openingQNUM = fopen('qnum/qnum.txt','w');
echo fwrite($openingQNUM,$newNum);
fclose($openingQNUM);
```

and I know I have called the functions right cause it is giving me the following error messages:

Warning: fopen(qnum/qnum.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\Hosting\11017597\html\Question Site\ask.php on line 16

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\Hosting\11017597\html\Question Site\ask.php on line 17

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\Hosting\11017597\html\Question Site\ask.php on line 18

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your hosting will not let you write the file where you are attempting to create it. What if you try this
$openingQNUM = fopen('D:\Hosting\11017597\html\Question Site\qnum\qnum.txt','w');

Answer (score 1):

PHP is complaining about not being able to create a new file because the filesystem denies access for writing. You should check if the process running PHP is allowed to write to the directory.

And in other news: ´file_put_contents()`does all of the above and is the counterpart of`file_get_contents()` - consider using it. It won't work right now, though, because of the file permission issue.

And after that: Welcome to the world of concurrent accesses! You are not using any form of locking, which makes your code a victim of race conditions. Two requests might read the same file (counter = 5), both increment the counter (= 6) and write back. Result: Counter is 6, but 7 would have been correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have read permissions on that file. Check if is_readable('qnum/qnum.txt') returns TRUE.